# Entropy description as in statistical mechanics but of transition phase between equilibrium states

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, reversibility

In statistical mechanics, entropy is defined based on possible number microstates. However, the entropy is defined only for equilibrium cases. For example, when two bodies of different temperature are brought in contact, the initial entropy is measured as the particles has limited scopes within the bodies and final entropy is measured as the particles can be anywhere within both bodies. Thus microstate and thus entropy increases. **However, I want to know the entropy of the transition phase when the heat exchange is taking place between the two bodies.**

Is there description possible for such cases in term statistical mechanics (I know statistical mechanics is made for equilibrium cases only)?
Or even in Thermodynamics, how do I **understand this variation of entropy with time clearly for different paths possible?**  In regard of this question, how do we **define a reversible process in statistical mechanics**? And **which path will be followed is determined by what?**